# How to find straight lines from an array of unsorted x/y cordinates

Tags: java, algorithm, line

Is there an efficient algorithm to find straight lines from an unsorted collection of x/y coordinates?
It would be ideal if:

- a line is only recognized if at least n (more than two) points are aligned.
- It allows a tolerance, so for example the following three coordinates would be considered a (horizontal) line: 10/100, 20/99, 30/100.

Is there some kind of standard approach to solve this? Maybe any (java) libraries? How would you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using two maps, one for horizontal lines and one for vertical ones.

for every point, the key is the X or Y coordinate and the value is the point (use a list of points as values). Now go over the maps, and for each key show the points if there are more than one point, for each key, you should also count the points in the next keys (like in the case of 99 and 100).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there'd be an efficient algorithm unless you already know of some relationship between the points.
The algorithm I outline below I guess would run in n^4 time.

You'd have something like

```
public class Line
{
    static float tolerance;
    float m, cLower, cUpper;
    ArrayList<Point> onThisLine = new ArrayList<Point>();

    public Line(double m, double c)
    {
        this.m = m;
        cLower = c-tolerance;
        cUpper = c+tolerance;
    }

    public boolean fitsInLine(Point xy)
    {...}

    public void addToList(Point xy)
    {...}
}
```

where m and c represent what we learned in high school as the gradient and constant of the straight line.

For each point you'd have to compare it to every other point, generate a Line object, and then compare the new Line object to every existing Line and if it doesn't already exist then add it.  Note that due to the slight tolerance you allow you consequentially have to allow for a similarity between Lines.
For example, y=-x/10+101 and y=100 are very similar line equations.

Finally, for each Line object you could get the size of the ArrayList keeping Points that fit on it, and throw away Lines that have less Points than what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a pair of points P<sub>i</sub> and P<sub>j</sub>, you can check in O(n) time which points lie on or near the line P<sub>i</sub> P<sub>j</sub>. There are O(n<sup>2</sup>) pairs, so you get an algorithm which is O(n<sup>3</sup>). Of course, if P<sub>k</sub> is exactly on the line P<sub>i</sub> P<sub>j</sub>, you should no longer check lines P<sub>i</sub> P<sub>k</sub> and P<sub>j</sub> P<sub>k</sub>, because they will contain the same points as P<sub>i</sub> P<sub>j</sub>. However, this is not true if P<sub>k</sub> is just close to P<sub>i</sub> P<sub>j</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the algorithm displayed below. What it does is it calculates the formula of the line: y= kx+l; Then it makes two lines parallel to that one, one slightly raised and one slightly lowered->(y = kx+l-d and y=kx+l+d, d=tolerance). Then it goes through the rest of points and calculates the y for their x for the upper and lower parallel. If it's real value is between the calculated values it counts as beeing on the line.This is O(n^3).
Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point[] points = generatePoints(5);

    List<Set<Point>> lines = findLines(points,2,3);

    lines.forEach((line)->{
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line.toArray()));
    });

}


private static List<Set<Point>> findLines(Point[] points,int tolerance,int minNumberOfPoints) {

    List<Set<Point>> lines = new LinkedList<>();

    for(int i=0;i<points.length;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<points.length;j++){
            //check if that line was all ready found
            boolean hasBoth = false;
            for(Set<Point> line:lines){
                hasBoth =Boolean.logicalAnd(line.contains(points[i]),line.contains(points[j]));
                if(hasBoth)
                    break;
            }
            if(hasBoth)
                break;

            int x1 = points[i].getX();
            int y1 = points[i].getY();
            int x2 = points[j].getX();
            int y2 = points[j].getY();

            double k = (double)(y1-y2)/(double)(x1-x2);
            double l = y1-k*x1;

            //y = kx + l -> line
            //y1 = kx + l - tolerance -> lower parallel line
            //y2 = kx + l + tolerance -> upper parallel line
            //take a third point if for its x it gives a y3 where y1<=y3<=y2 then it should be part of the line

            Set<Point> line = new HashSet<>();
            line.add(points[i]);
            line.add(points[j]);

            for(int z=j+1;z<points.length;z++){
                int x3 = points[z].getX();
                int y3 = points[z].getY();

                double y1Line = k*x3+l-tolerance;
                double y2Line = k*x3+l+tolerance;
                if(y1Line<=y3 && y3<=y2Line)
                    line.add(points[z]);
            }
            lines.add(line);
        }
    }

    lines = lines.stream().filter((set)->{
        return set.size()>=minNumberOfPoints;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return lines;
}

private static Point[] generatePoints(int number) {
    Point[] points = new Point[number];
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
        points[i] = new Point(r.nextInt(10), r.nextInt(10));
    }
    return points;
}

private static class Point{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public Point(int x,int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "("+x+","+y+")";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Hough transformation to detect lines. I experienced hough transformation while detecting features in images. It basically uses polar representation of lines to detect them. Although I think opencv is out of the context for what you want to do, I still want to share the hough line detection page with you which explains the algorithm pretty clearly.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

There is also this source which I had found to be useful :

https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~hamarneh/ecopy/compvis1999_hough.pdf